# Backbone: Rendering Nested Views

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm using Backbone for the first time and I'm trying to work out how to render a view inside a view. My parent view is showing up on the page perfectly, I just can't seem to render the nested view inside `<div id="activity-feed"></div>`.

My parent view can seen below:

**views/project_post_items.coffee**

```
define ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'templates', 'views/shared/project_post_item'],
($, _, Backbone, JST, ProjectPostItemView) ->
  class ProjectPostItemsView extends Backbone.View
    template: JST['app/scripts/templates/charity/project_post_items.ejs']
    posts_item_views: []

    initialize: ->
      super()

      @listenTo @model, 'change', @render
      if @model.dirty()
        @model.fetch()
      else
        @render()

      @listenTo(@collection, 'add', @displayPostItem)
      @collection.reset().fetch(add: true)

    displayPostItem: (project) ->
      view = new ProjectPostItemView(model: project)
      @posts_item_views.push( view.on('render', =>
        @$('#activity-feed').append(view.$('>'))) )

    render: (options) ->
      super(options)
```

I'm adding my post items to my collection, then creating a new `ProjectPostItemView` view with my `displayPostItem()` function and pushing these items onto my `posts_item_views` array. Finally I'm appending the items to an element with an id of `#activity-feed`.

And this is the template it's linked to:

**templates/project_post_items.ejs**

```
<h2>Latest Updates</h2>

<div id="activity-feed"></div>
```

My sub-view (`ProjectPostItemView`) looks like this:

**views/project_post_item.coffee**

```
define ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'templates', 'models/project_post_item'],
($, _, Backbone, JST, ProjectPostItemModel) ->
  class ProjectPostItemView extends Backbone.View
    template: JST['app/scripts/templates/shared/project_post_item.ejs']

    initialize: (options) ->
      @main_view = options.main_view
      super()
      console.log "hello"
      @render

    render: =>
      super({}, 'html')
```

And its template like this:

**templates/project_post_item.ejs**

```
<h1>Hello from the nested view</h1>
```

That "hello" message is being printed to the console 4 times, which is exactly the amount of items I have in that collection.

[image]

So it's doing something right. I just want to know how can I render this template to the parent view. Very new to Backbone.js and I can't work out what I'm doing wrong.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

To the request of @Mathletics, I've added a bit more code to shed light on how the template is being attached to the DOM.

**main.coffee**

```
injectPageView: (sub_view, options={}) ->
  # clean and switch
  @current_page_view?.remove()
  # set up the new one
  @current_page_view = new sub_view(_.defaults(options, el: @$page_container, main_view: @))
  @side_menu_view.activate_item(_.result(@current_page_view, 'item_menu'))
  @listenTo(@current_page_view, 'url:fragment', (fragment) => @router.navigate("home/#{fragment}", trigger: false))
  @
```

**charity_router.coffee**

```
posts: (project_id) ->
  @main_view.injectPageView( ProjectPostItemsView, model: @data.charity, collection: @data.charity.getProjectPostItems(project_id) )
```

Comment: I'm not certain but for start, looks to me like you have a problem in your first `define` call. Looks like `ProjectView` doesn't belong there.

Comment: What are you expecting to render the sub-views?

Comment: That's a typo. Stripped down the original code, hence the mistake.

Comment: Fixed the typo @Amit.

Comment: @muistooshort Sorry, can you elaborate?

Comment: Any console errors? Did you use a debugger to see anything at all?

Comment: @Amit No console errors.

Comment: You say you're having trouble rendering nested views but I don't see where your code is supposed to be rendering them.

Comment: @muistooshort That's what I don't understand how to write. I'm trying to find out how I can simply just render what's in the `templates/project_post_item.ejs` to the `#activity-feed` element?

Comment: @realph is `#activity-feed` a descendant of the your parent view's rendered HTML and is your parent `el` attached to the DOM before you try rendering the sub-views? I'm not seeing where you parent view is attached to the DOM.

Comment: My parent view is attached to the DOM, the parent template (templates/project_post_items.ejs - shown above) is rendering itself on the page. Just can't get the sub-view to render inside that `#activity-feed`.

Comment: @muistooshort I've added an `initialize()` and `render()` func to my sub-view's view, but how can I get the template its pointing to (templates/project_post_item.ejs), to render?

Comment: @realph `render` is, by default, a no-op. your methods include a call to `super` but don't show how the actual template result is getting attached to the DOM. Perhaps you should show your super-`render` method.

Comment: @Mathletics I've added a bit more code to the original question above.

Comment: None of the code you've added actually shows interaction with the DOM. Help us help you.

Comment: @Mathletics Sorry, I'm not sure what should I be looking for? This isn't my codebase so still trying to find my way around it.